# How to run Spark processes in develop environment using a cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, jenkins, intellij-idea, amazon-emr, databricks

I'm implementing differents Apache Spark solutions using IntelliJ IDEA, Scala and SBT, however, each time that I want to run my implementation I need to do the next steps after creating the jar:

- Amazon: To send the .jar to the master node using SSH, and then run
  the command line spark-shell.
- Azure: I'm using Databricks CLI, so each time that I want to upload a
  jar, I uninstall the old library, remove the jar stored in the cluster,
  and finally, I upload and install the new .jar.

So I was wondering if it is possible to do all these processes just in one click, using the IntelliJ IDEA RUN button for example, or using another method to make simpler all of it. Also, I was thinking about Jenkins as an alternative.

Basically, I'm looking for easier deployment options.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, would Databricks Connect (https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html) solve this, or are you looking for easier deployment options?

Comment: Yes, Databricks is one possible option. Is it possible without databricks do something similar?

Comment: Would you like to deploy automatically when you commit some changes to repository, or it should be done on request?

Comment: Preferably on request.